# Inheritance of non access modifiers

Tags: java, inheritance, access-modifiers

What are the rules or can you provide clear information on what happens to the non access modifiers for a field and for methods, while inheritance.
Ex:

```
class Super {
    public final int x; 

    protected strictfp final printX() {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}

class Sub extends Super {
}
```

What non access modifiers do the inherited x and printX have? Can you provide link to detailed rules on this?

Comment: SO isnt exactly a service for googling java language spec for you... it is there, section 8.4.8

Comment: Btw, `super` is a keyword, so this won't compile. Use the Java naming conventions and name your classes starting with a capital (`Super`).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8

Comment: Thanks. As most of the explanations are about changing the access modifiers and how it works, difficult to get explanation for how non access modifier work during inheritance. Joni answer cleared the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance refers to how members of the superclass are accessible through the subclass; the subclass will not actually get copies of its own. This means that `x` and `printX` will still have the exact same modifiers when accessed in the subclass, since they actually are still declared in the superclass.